# Concatenate 2 dataframes. I would like to combine duplicate columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The following code can be used as an example of the problem I'm having:

```
dic={'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)

dic2={'A':['4','5','6'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df3=pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
print(df3)
```

The result I get from this concatenation is:

```
     B    B
1   10  NaN
2   11  NaN
3   12  NaN
4  NaN   10
5  NaN   11
6  NaN   12
```

I would like to have:

```
     B    
1   10 
2   11 
3   12 
4   10
5   11
6   12
```

I know that I can concatenate along axis=0.  Unfortunately, that only solves the problem for this little example.  The actual code I'm working with is more complex.  Concatenating along axis=0 causes the index to be duplicated.  I don't want that either.

EDIT:

People have asked me to give a more complex example to describe why simply removing 'axis=1' doesn't work.  Here is a more complex example, first with axis=1 INCLUDED:

```
dic={'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)

dic2={'A':['4','5','6'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

dic3={'A':['1','2','3'], 'C':['20','21','22']}
df3=pd.DataFrame(dic3)
df3.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df4=pd.concat([df,df3], axis=1)
print(df4)
```

This gives me:

```
     B    B    C
1   10  NaN   20
2   11  NaN   21
3   12  NaN   22
4  NaN   10  NaN
5  NaN   11  NaN
6  NaN   12  NaN
```

I would like to have:

```
     B    C    
1   10   20
2   11   21
3   12   22
4   10  NaN
5   11  NaN
6   12  NaN
```

Now here is an example with axis=1 REMOVED:

```
dic={'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)

dic2={'A':['4','5','6'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2])

dic3={'A':['1','2','3'], 'C':['20','21','22']}
df3=pd.DataFrame(dic3)
df3.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df4=pd.concat([df,df3])
print(df4)
```

This gives me:

```
     B    C
A          
1   10  NaN
2   11  NaN
3   12  NaN
4   10  NaN
5   11  NaN
6   12  NaN
1  NaN   20
2  NaN   21
3  NaN   22
```

I would like to have:

```
     B    C    
1   10   20
2   11   21
3   12   22
4   10  NaN
5   11  NaN
6   12  NaN
```

Sorry it wasn't very clear.  I hope this helps.

Comment: `df3=pd.concat([df1,df2])`, without the `axis`.

Comment: If your real example is "more complicated" I suggest you create an example that is representative of that problem so you can get the answer you need.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the original question to be more representative of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two step process, for the example provided after the 'EDIT' point.  Start by creating the dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

dic  = {'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
dic2 = {'A':['4','5','6'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
dic3 = {'A':['1','2','3'], 'C':['20','21','22']}
```

Step 1: convert each dictionary to a data frame, with index 'A', and concatenate (along axis=0):

```
t = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dic).set_index('A'),
               pd.DataFrame(dic2).set_index('A'),
               pd.DataFrame(dic3).set_index('A')])
```

Step 2:  concatenate non-null elements of col 'B' with non-null elements of col 'C' (you could put this in a list comprehension if there are more than two columns).  Now we concatenate along axis=1:

```
result = pd.concat([
    t.loc[ t['B'].notna(), 'B' ],
    t.loc[ t['C'].notna(), 'C' ],
], axis=1)

print(result)

    B    C
1  10   20
2  11   21
3  12   22
4  10  NaN
5  11  NaN
6  12  NaN
```

Comment: I did this via list comprehension like you recommended and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

If two objects need to be added along axis=1, then the new columns will be appended.And with axis=0 or default same column will be appended with new values.

Refer Below Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

dic={'A':['1','2','3'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)

dic2={'A':['4','5','6'], 'B':['10','11','12']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2]) 

dic3={'A':['1','2','3'], 'C':['20','21','22']}
df3=pd.DataFrame(dic3)
df3.set_index('A', inplace=True)

df4=pd.concat([df,df3],axis=1) #As here C is new new column so need to use axis=1
print(df4)
```

Output:

```
    B    C
1  10   20
2  11   21
3  12   22
4  10  NaN
5  11  NaN
6  12  NaN
```

Comment: Please see the updated question.  My problem is a little more complicated than the sample I originally used.  I've included a better example which is more representative of my problem.

Comment: I have updated the solution ,you can refer for reference .